# Search field doesn't exactly respect tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I can search for tags like `[python]` etc from the search field and they work. But I searched for `[foobar]` on the android app and it should have returned nothing, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foobar). But it shows questions that has foobar somewhere in the body or title -

[image: android app searching foobar tag]

It should say no result found. BTW that's also an issue. If there is no result for the given query, the page just stays empty. It should say something.

Comment: What happens when you search for an *actual* tag? Like `[c++]` or `[perl]`?

Comment: It works http://d.pr/i/ZAID/yKxw7OAa

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, we figured out the cause and it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

Search within the android app now works much like the site search, so using [asp.net] should return all posts tagged as such.